# Overwatch Workshop: set payload starting position?

Tags: overwatch

Is there any way to affect the payload's position with workshop rules?

I've found a lot of tutorials, and none of them affect the behavior of the payload. (Although there is a cute one that makes heroes magnetically drawn to the payload).

I've found how to *get* the position of the payload, but not how to *set* it. Is that possible?

NOTE: I haven't been able to find a comprehensive list of the keywords for the workshop (let alone documentation), so those links would be helpful, too.

Answer (score -4):

Currently, no there is no such way. but they are working on it, according to an inside guy I have in OW team, however you still can manually modify gamefiles on your own, given that you have knowledge of C++. and are able to reverse engineer, for which I recommend
https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/overwatch/216905-overwatch-reversal-structs-offsets.html
a collective of people have worked on reverse engineering OW for years, there you can find the proper files to edit without having to debug the game on your own.
However note that, anticheats might consider it a violation of rules which could ultimately result in your getting banned.

Comment: The information you're linking to is intended for cheat developers -- it relates to the locations of specific data _in memory_, not in data files. This isn't any use for developing Workshop mods.